# Facebook sdk ignores fields filtering

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the newest Facebook SDK for Android and try to get the albums of a user but only several fields of them.
My problem is that the fields param gets ignored and I get all data like likes etc....
What's wrong with my request?

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "count,name,id,created_time,updated_time,photos");
Request request = new Request(session, "me/albums", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println(response);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Requires the user_photos or friend_photos permission
```

You need that permission!